# There is an error in the id of the buttons, that is, when throwing from activity to activity

Tags: android, kotlin

Two buttons are created in android studio and they are given an id, for example, when you click the **first one**, you need to enter **first activity**, and when you click the **second one**, you need to enter **second activity**, but what should be done so that even when you click **two buttons**, they do not enter **one activity**

> Both buttons point to the same activity

Comment: Please provide xml and java/kt source code for better understanding.

Comment: Please provide enough details so anyone can understand that exactly what is the problem in your code.